# Not getting data from ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why this is not working:

```
idcurso= res[0];
idusuario= res[1];
semana= res[2];
fecha=res[3];
asistencia= true;
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/test/7/tomarasistencia.php',
     data: {
         idcurso:idcurso,idusuario:idusuario,semana:semana,fecha:fecha,asistencia:asistencia
     },
     success: function (response) {
         console.log("response: "+response);
     }
});
```

no problems at this point,

and in php:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $idcurso = $_POST['idcurso'];
    $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'];
    $semana = $_POST['semana'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $asistencia = $_POST['asistencia'];

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO faltas (IdAlumno, IdCurso, IdUsuarioModificaFalta, FechaModificaFalta, fechafalta,comentario,inactivo,asistencia,semana) VALUES ('$idusuario','$idcurso','$_SESSION[id]',now(),'$fecha','',false,'$asistencia','$semana')";
    //la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    $resent=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query1) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
    echo 'de php: '.$idusuario.' '.$idcurso.' '.$semana.' '.$fecha.' '.$asistencia;
?>
```

all the php variables in php are empty.

Comment: Check what data ajax is sending to the server in the Network tab of your browser developer tools.

Comment: You forgot some code in your sample... where does `res` come from to do `res[0]` ?

Comment: from a split i did previusly, I have no proble on the js part, all the variables have the correct value, but I am not able to get those values on php

Comment: `idcurso:37
idusuario:460
semana:3
fecha:2017-11-08
asistencia:true` thats what I get in the network tab, the data is sent correctly

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax request, are you sure of "type: "POST""? The doc says "method: "POST". I think your data are sent with the GET method.

Comment: I have used type:"POST" before without any problem, just haven't tried this with php until now, ill try method tho

Comment: In your PHP, try "var_dump($_REQUEST);". You should see your data (GET or POST).

Comment: got it, was the or die part, i have the data on php now, the problem was with the insert query, i still need to figure out why its not inserting

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thank you all for your help, it was a problem with my query and the or die part was preventing me to echo the variables